# Red Black Tree - Print Error

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, red-black-tree

I am trying to implement Red Black tree after studying about it but getting error while printing the Red Black tree. Can you please have a look and suggest whether there is anything wrong in the implementation of the Red Black Tree insertion.
It shows only root and it's first left and right child recursively and then shows the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
at RedBlackTree.preOrder(RedBlackTree.java:161)
at RedBlackTree.preOrder(RedBlackTree.java:162)
at RedBlackTree.preOrder(RedBlackTree.java:162)
at RedBlackTree.preOrder(RedBlackTree.java:163)
```

Last two lines of error is repeated many times.

For print command I am using simple Pre-Order recursive code.
Following is the code :

```
public class RedBlackTree {

public RBNode root;

void leftRotate(RBNode node)
{
    RBNode y;
    y = node.right;
    if(y.left != null)y.left.parent = node;
    y.parent = node.parent;

    if(node.parent == null)root = y;
    else
    {
        if(node == node.parent.left)node.parent.left = y;
        else node.parent.right =y;
    }
    y.left = node;
    node.parent = y;
}

void rightRotate(RBNode node)
{
    RBNode y;
    y = node.left;
    if(y.right != null)y.right.parent = node;
    y.parent = node.parent;

    if(node.parent == null)root = y;
    else
    {
        if(node == node.parent.right)node.parent.right = y;
        else node.parent.left =y;
    }
    y.right = node;
    node.parent = y;
}

void insertNode(RBNode node, RBNode data)
{
    // INSERT IN ROOT
    if(node == null)
    {
        node = new RBNode(data.key);
        root = node;
        root.color = 0;
        System.out.println("Root " + root.key);

    }

    else if (data.key < node.key && node.left == null)
    {

        node.left = data;
        data.parent = node;



    }
    else if(data.key >node.key && node.right == null)
    {

        node.right  = data;
        data.parent = node;


    }

    else{
        if(data.key < node.key)insertNode(node.left, data);
        else insertNode(node.right, data);
    }

    data.color = 1;


    RBNode uncle;
    //Check REB BLACK PROPERTIES

    while(data.parent != null && data.parent.color ==1 && data != root && data.color != 0)
    {
                System.out.println("Data " + data.key + " Parent " + data.parent.key);

                //PARENT IS RIGHT CHILD
                if(data.parent == data.parent.parent.right)
                {
                    System.out.println("Parent RIGHT");
                    uncle = data.parent.parent.left; 
                    if(uncle == null) System.out.println("Uncle is null");

                    //UNCLE IS BLACK OR NULL
                    if(uncle == null || uncle.color == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Uncle BLACK or NULL");
                        if(data == data.parent.left)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Node is LEFT");
                            data = data.parent;
                            rightRotate(data);
                        }
                        data.parent.color = 0;
                        if(data.parent.parent.key != root.key)data.parent.parent.color = 1;
                        leftRotate(data.parent.parent);
                    }
                    //UNCLE IS RED
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Uncle RED");
                        data.parent.parent.left.color = 0;
                        data.parent.color = 0;
                        if(data.parent.parent.key != root.key)data.parent.parent.color = 1;
                        data = data.parent;
                    }


                }
                // PARENT IS LEFT CHILD
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Parent LEFT");
                    uncle = data.parent.parent.right; 
                    //UNCLE IS NULL OR BLACK
                    if(uncle ==null || uncle.color == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Uncle BLACK or NULL");
                        System.out.println("");
                        if(data == data.parent.right)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Node is RIGHT");
                            data = data.parent;
                            leftRotate(data);
                        }
                        data.parent.color = 0;
                        if(data.parent.parent.key != root.key)data.parent.parent.color = 1;
                        rightRotate(data.parent.parent);    
                    }
                    //UNCLE IS RED
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Uncle RED");

                        data.parent.parent.right.color = 0;
                        data.parent.color = 0;
                        if(data.parent.parent.key != root.key)data.parent.parent.color= 1;
                        data = data.parent;
                    }

                }


    }
    root.color = 0;

}

void preOrder(RBNode node)
{
    if(node != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Value : " + node.key + "Color: " + node.color);
        preOrder(node.left);
        preOrder(node.right);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    RedBlackTree tree = new RedBlackTree();
    tree.insertNode(tree.root, new RBNode(2));
    tree.insertNode(tree.root, new RBNode(1));
    tree.insertNode(tree.root, new RBNode(4));
    tree.insertNode(tree.root, new RBNode(5));
    tree.insertNode(tree.root, new RBNode(9));
    tree.insertNode(tree.root, new RBNode(3));
    tree.insertNode(tree.root, new RBNode(6));

    tree.insertNode(tree.root, new RBNode(7));


    tree.preOrder(tree.root);
  }


}

class RBNode
{
 int key; 
 RBNode parent;
 RBNode left;
 RBNode right;
 int color;  // 1 = RED , 0 = BLACK
public RBNode(int key)
 {
    this.key = key;
    this.parent = null;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;


 }
}
```

Is the insertion implementation wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide the entire code with your imports and full staff so that we can compile and debug the code?

Comment: @PyPiper - Please check edited question. I have entered entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve that particular error so code is still not giving the entire correct answer. Error was coming out because of wrong implementation of Left and Right rotation.

```
void leftRotate(RBNode node)
{
    RBNode y;
    y = node.right;
    node.right = y.left;

    if(y.left != null)y.left.parent = node;

    y.parent = node.parent;

    if(node.parent == null)root = y;
    else
    {
        if(node == node.parent.left)node.parent.left = y;
        else node.parent.right =y;
    }
    y.left = node;
    node.parent = y;
}

void rightRotate(RBNode node)
{
    RBNode y;
    y = node.left;
    node.left = y.right;
    if(y.right != null)y.right.parent = node;

    y.parent = node.parent;

    if(node.parent == null)root = y;
    else
    {
        if(node == node.parent.right)node.parent.right = y;
        else node.parent.left =y;
    }
    y.right = node;
    node.parent = y;
}
```